# See download time remaining in macOS Catalina App Store

Tags: mac-appstore, catalina

After upgrading to macOS Catalina, the download progess indicator changed to an IOS-style circle, which doesn't give the more specific details of download speed and time remaining that were visible in previous versions. Is there any way to still see how long an app will take to download/upgrade?

[image]